# Is it possible to not save Facebook chat history?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I would like to not retain my Facebook chat history. Instead of deleting every chat, is there an option for this?

Comment: Why Downvotes what's wrong in this question?

Answer (score 1):

No, there no such option for it yet... You have option to delete your conversation but the other person or other group from which your conversation was going will have no effect on their side.

Comment: Dude  know that I can delete conversation and I also know that deleting chat history on my side will never effect the other person you totally took my question wrong I asked about saving the history and you answered about deleting it anyway thanks for your attempt